# Does Psalm 45:6 and Hebrews 1:8 say, "Your throne, God, is forever" or "Your throne is God forever"?

Tags: psalms, hebrews, kingdom-of-god, throne-of-god

Traditional translation:

> Your throne, **God, is** forever and ever.

Or this translation:

> Your throne **is God** forever and ever.

A significant clue is that the context is written about a human Israelite king who himself also serves as a foreshadow of Jesus, as the author of the book of Hebrews reveals.

Wouldn't this passage be saying that the throne of God's king comes from God and thereby represents his sovereign authority on earth? *It certainly cannot be saying that the king himself is literally God.*

The surrounding contextual clues actually favor strongly against the traditional translation in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Truth**

As is obvious in several Psalms, the vocative “O God” comes in the middle of sentences. This is visible in the Septuagint also.

Literal Hebrew Bible at Psalms 45:6:

> “Your throne, God, forever and ever”.

Literal Greek Septuagint at Psalms 44:7:

> “The throne of you, O God, to the age of the age”.

[Note:- Since the Greek Septuagint was translated around 250 years before Christ, the translators had no cause to be prejudiced against Jesus. So they translated with the obvious first meaning.]

Literal NT quotes in Hebrews 1:8:

> “The throne of you, O God, to the age of the age”.

**Vocative in the Middle in Other Psalms** (in Septuagint)

- 39:9 : “To do Your will, O my God, I desired”
- 54:2 : “Give ear, O God, to my prayer”.
- 54:24 : “But You, O God, will bring down the wicked”
- 59:12 : “Is it not You, O God, You who have rejected us?”
- 64:2 : “Praise awaits You, O God, in Zion”.
- 68:30 : “May Your salvation, O God, protect me”.
- 70:17 : “Since my youth, O God, You have taught me”.
- 138:23 : “Search me, O God, and know my heart”.

**Benefit of Doubt**

**IF** Psalms 45:6 and Hebrews 1:8 are meant to be “God is your throne forever and ever”, then:

a)  It will show that Christ is greater than God!! Definitely the one sitting on the throne is greater than the throne itself. But this is unscriptural. Jesus Christ Himself said clearly that God the Father is greater than Him in authority. So, God cannot be dwindled into a mere throne. Neither is He a throne of others nor is He a footstool of others.

OR

b)  As some say, this means the authority of the king comes from God. **IF** this is so, then what about the following Scripture:

> “But I say to you not to swear at all, neither by **heaven** for it
> **is the throne of God**” (Matt 5:34).

**IF** (b) above is correct, then, according to Matthew 5:34, the Almighty God gets His authority from Heaven!!

Heaven is the throne of God and so, according to the above funny interpretation, it is the Heaven that gives all the authority to God ***making Heaven greater than*** the Almighty God. So, obviously, option (b) above cannot be true thus making option (a) correct proving that Jesus is addressed as “O God”.

[Even when God says that He has made Moses a god (Exo 7:1), He doesn’t say that “God is Moses’ throne”!]

**Another Hurdle for the Deniers**

Hebrews 1:10 is addressed to the Christ, the Son of God:

> “And, "You, **Lord**, at the beginning founded the earth, and the
> heavens are works of Your hands.”

This is a direct quote from Psalms 102:25-27.

The problem is, Psalms 102 is addressed, without any doubt, to none other than Yahweh God Himself as is clearly shown in verses 1, 12, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21, 22, and 24.

Suddenly, in the very next verse (verse 25), “You founded the earth” means “Yahweh founded the earth”.

And the author of Hebrews uses this verse **pointing** to Jesus Christ. This proves, beyond any doubt, that he considers Jesus as the Yahweh God of Psalms 102!!

**Conclusion**

As a person who has studied this single topic diligently over several years, I am sure that whichever way we look at the Scripture and from whatever angle we strain our eyes searching through the Scripture, the truth will shine through:

That the Lord Jesus Christ is the Yahweh of the Old Testament who interacted actively with the first Parents, the Patriarchs, and the Prophets.

Comment: I actually agree with you that Jesus was the Lord YHWH of the old testament. He came from God to represent God on earth without himself being God. Being God's own Son, Jesus was the Angel of YHWH and could say on behalf of God that he was God, because God gave him his own name, YHWH, and all the authority that comes along with it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation showing the vocative in the middle of other Psalms. I am firmly convinced now that it says, "Your throne, God, is everlasting."

Comment: Thumbs down for declaring the literal Greek to be an English translation and not acknowledging that the Greek Septuagint translation of this verse has the exact same nominative ambiguity as the Greek New Testament quotation of it. The grammar does not decisively demand that the literal English translation of the LXX must be "O God."

Comment: +1. Excellent answer.  Many thanks, and well done.

Comment: Thank you very much, Joshua B, for the positive feedback.

Comment: Thank you, Dottard. An appreciation from you made me happy. Hope you reach 100K reputation soon. Seems to be a record!

Comment: @Austin – I know the “nominative ambiguity” is to do with the “O” of “O God”. Removal of the “O” does not make any difference. “Come on, O John, sit here” = “Come on, hey John, sit here” = “Come on, John, sit here”. These all have the same meaning and are different from “John comes on and sits here”.

Comment: @NepheshRoi, it completely changes the meaning of the verse to your throne is God forever and ever. It's similar to saying God is your rock meaning God is your foundation or God is your shield meaning God will give you protection. Saying God is your throne is saying that you will rule by the power granted by God. When two nominative nouns are set together without an explicit verb connecting them the translator may supply the implicit verb "is" to express the relationship between the two nominative nouns.

Comment: Interesting. But then how can you explain the other vocative uses on other passages of Psalms?

Comment: @Austin – God is your Rock “and _that Rock was Christ_”, so says Apostle Paul in 1 Cor 10:4. You are also right, the implicit verb “is” is placed correctly in the predicate when the vocative is in the middle of the sentence, as, “the throne of you, O God, “is” to the age of the age”. Besides, if you were right, then Heb 1:10-12, in clear reference to Psalms 102:25-27, will prove that “_God is the throne of YHWH_”!!

Comment: @NepheshRoi the reason why I thumbs down is because you assume it's vocative when it is clearly nominative and so it seems you continue to do so. It's not vocative. It's nominative, which is often interpreted as a nominative form used as a vocative. Regarding , Heb 1:10-12, there's grammatical and contextual and logical reasons for understanding that person addressed in Heb 1:8 is not the same as is addressed in 10-12, but that's a whole other subject.

Comment: @JoshuaB, I just realized that your last comment might have been meant for me. The the other vocative uses make sense because those other Psalms were obviously contextually applied to the God, however in this case the addressee is obviously a human Israeli ruler with a queen so there's no need to assume that God is the addressee in this passage. Your original instincts were correct. When the grammar is ambigous you rely on the context and the context is striaghtforward.

Comment: @Austin – Yet, in the Greek we refer to, the nominative is used as the vocative as is amply evident in the Psalms. The context makes the difference. A human “messiah” was not a problem at all to the Jewish expectation of the first century. After all, there were several Jewish superstars claiming to be “messiahs” (Acts 5:36-37; 21:38). Only the Romans had problems with them.             (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd)         Yet, God’s precious gift was way higher than the Jewish expectation, as usual (Isaiah 55:9). God Himself came down as the Messiah. And that made a heaven of a problem to the parochial Jewish minds! And, the old Jewish legacy still prevails in those who resist this truth; the “veil” still lies on their minds in understanding the OT which can be removed only in realizing Jesus Christ as the Yahweh (2 Cor 3:15-16).

Comment: I had forgotten about your thumbs down. I have no problem with thumbs down.

Comment: @NepheshRoi, fine. Don't mind the thumbs down, but perhaps mind misrepresenting scriptural evidence. That's a nice story. I'm not trying to convince you that Jesus is not God, but to accurately represent the ambiguity in the LXX as well as the NT. It's true that sometimes the nominative is used as vocative, but sometimes the nominative is nominative. You must rely on the immediate context (over some grand narrative, or examples in other chapters) to resolve that immedate ambiguity like in all languages. You say the LXX literally translated the Hebrew as "O God." It factually did not.

Comment: @Austin – I will be the last person to misrepresent the Scripture. To you it may be “a nice story” but it is the truth. You have no qualms in using the nominative as vocative in other Psalms (your comment to Joshua B) except in this particular verse where your ‘a priori’ theological leanings prevent you from the truth which is determined by the grammatical and contextual evidences. You talked about the immediate context but I gave you the same already. Heb 1:8 – “_but as to the Son_”, quotes Psalms 45:6-7 “**_and_**” Psalms 102:25-27 proving that Jesus is the Yahweh of the OT!

Comment: @NepheshRoi, you should be more humble. I'm sure everyone at one point or another misinterprets scripture to someone else and has thus misrepresented it myself included. Not saying you did anything on purpose. But to respond as if there is no grammatical ambiguity in the LXX is a misrepresentation when that's what the question is about. See Dottard's answer. He at least cites a scholar who points out that the Greek supports both interpretations, yet argues to *"prefer"* one over the other. Intellectual honesty would admit this to be the case & not claim victory before the argument is made.

Comment: @NepheshRoi, regarding nominative as vocative in other Psalms, none of the other Psalms you quoted the structure of Psalms 45:6 where God is in apposition to another nominative in the Greek.  None except Psalms 64:2. All the other examples are irrelevant. In Psalms 64:2 in the LXX,  *God in Zion* may be the description of the addressee who is obviously God, or the name of the hymn of which is fitting for one who is obviously God. In the case Psalms 45 the addressee is obviously not God. See also PS 7:11; 46:1;47:7;54:4;62:8;73:26 where God is used in apposition to other nominations in Greek.

Comment: @Austin – I am humble but that doesn’t mean that I have to agree with all the opinions. At the same time, I respect others’ rights to hold to their opinions. I do painstakingly retest my conviction from which stems my comments/answers. So, I am not close-minded as you may suppose.

Comment: I agree Dottard cited a scholar, but I am citing an inspired NT author himself who collocated Psalms 45:6-7 and 102:25-27 applying them “to the Son” proving that the Son is the Yahweh of OT. Now if you insist I can be sympathetic to the idea that God is the throne of Yahweh but then I can see distinctly a “You” and a “King” in Psalms 45:5 (the immediately previous verse of the OP).

Comment: @NepheshRoi, regarding humility, that was concerning: *"I will be the last person to misrepresent the Scripture."* That is a wild thing for the self-ware to say, as if anyone on this exchange thinks they're misrepresenting scriptural evidence.  Otherwise, I wouldn't presume to speak on your humility.  Ultimately, my problem is with your note on how the LXX "had no cause to be prejudiced against Jesus. So they translated with the obvious first meaning," as if the ambiguity was only in the Hebrew and is thus resolved in the Greek when clear scholarship shows that it is not in this way resolved.

Comment: Thus you used the LXX translation in a way that the informed and intellectual honest would not. This misrepresents the Greek. It's not the Greek translators that support your claim, but the English translation of the Greek.   Your view seems to be informed not primarily upon the original literal meaning of the LXX,  but on the NT author's statements as translated in English. If you would have acknowledged the grammar ambiguity (either, "your throne is God forever" or "your throne, O God, is forever" and then made your NT argument, I would have had nothing to say.

Comment: @Austin – When I say ‘I am okay’, it doesn’t mean that I mean others aren’t okay. I simply meant to state that there is no incongruence between my conviction and comments. Again, I don’t claim others have such problem. Now it is my firm conviction that a Christian cannot understand the OT without the NT. And the NT states what it states regarding Jesus as being the Yahweh of the OT as I have explained in my comments.

Comment: @NepheshRoi, *Now it is my firm conviction that a Christian cannot understand the OT without the NT.* I'm largely in aggreement here. The problem in your answer is that you give the clear impression that the Greek translators of the Old Testament agree with your preferred English interpretation/translation of Ps. 44:7 or Heb 1:8 based on the English translation of the LXX when you actually don't have enough information from the Greek LXX to say the original translators agreed with you because they left the ambiguity in the text they  translated into Greek.

Comment: In other words, your case rests with other NT claims you think apply to Ps 44:7 and not exclusively on the translation choices in Greek of the LXX.

Comment: @Austin – Thank you for considering “my firm conviction”. I would like to agree with you. But then, to make things short, according to the inspired author of Hebrews, “**_God is the throne_** (Psalms 45:6 and Heb 1:8) **_of Yahweh_** (Psalms 102:25-27 and Heb 1:10-12).

Comment: @NepheshRoi, very good. My point is that even if your interpretation of Hebrews 1:8-10 was correct, your statement, *"the Greek Septuagint was translated around 250 years before Christ, the translators had no cause to be prejudiced against Jesus. **So they translated with the obvious first meaning,"*** is still incorrect since they did not translate the verse in a way that could on its own resolve the ambiguity. They left it in there. The first meaning is in no  way obvious from syntax of the translation.  That's why you need your interpretation of Heb 1:10-12 to get there.

Comment: @Austin – The ambiguity may be in your mind but not in the mind of the inspired author of Hebrews. I am aware of the group of people who cherish this ambiguity which arises from certain pre-conceived notions. Had there been any ambiguity, as you claim, the inspired author of Hebrews would not have used it in connection with Yahweh (Psalms 102:25-27 and Heb 1:10-12). He is the one who confirms it to me that the original reading is, “Your throne, O God/Yahweh, forever and ever”.

Comment: @NepheshRoi It's not my mind it's in the mind of all familiar w/ the LXX including the trinitarian scholar Dottard quoted arising not from my bias. Regarding, "Had there been any ambiguity, as you claim, the inspired author of Hebrews would not have used it in connection with Yahweh." Even given your interpretation of Heb1:10-12, this is a bad read. The scripture reports that the meaning of OT prophecy was hidden from prophets (let alone translators) so that ambiguities can only be clarified by later revelation (1Pe1:10-12,Dan12:8-9). Acknowledging ambiguity in LXX is simply telling the truth.

Comment: @Austin – To state that the prophets in the OT didn’t understand any part of the prophecy they wrote is not simply true. They did understand much of the prophecy (Dan 9:2, 22-23). But it is true that a full understanding was given to the apostles in the NT through the Holy Spirit (1 Cor 2:10). So, I stand by my statement: had there been any ambiguity, the inspired author of Hebrews would not have used it. I (politely) consider the modern scholars (even early church fathers) only as secondary to the NT apostles.

Comment: @NepheshRoi, if the Bible reports that *multiple prophets* (1 Pet 1:10:-12, Dan 12:8-9) did not understand *even a portion* of the prophecies they spoke and no Bible verse states that all prophets (let alone translators) understood every word they prophesied, then the *assumption* that just because a NT author understood something then the *translators* into a language other than the original must have also understood the same is completely unsupported by scripture as being true, and willfully ignoring how the Greek in the LXX works in favor of this unfounded assumption is simply unjustified.

Comment: @Austin - I think we have come to a dead end. Let us part in peace.

Answer (score 2):

Let us examine these two texts separately.

**Psalm 45:6**

The text of this verse is (with my literal translation with which all except one translation agrees:

> כִּסְאֲךָ֣ אֱ֭לֹהִים עֹולָ֣ם וָעֶ֑ד שֵׁ֥בֶט מִ֝ישֹׁ֗ר שֵׁ֣בֶט
> מַלְכוּתֶֽךָ = You throne, God, forever and ever - a scepter of
> righteousness [the] scepter of your kingdom

Let us observe several things about this verse:

- there is no "is" (verb to be) describing God as the throne.  Rather, we have a simple chain of nouns which must be (if we be very pedantic) translated, "Your throne of God forever ... ".  That is, God is not the throne, but the throne is that of which belongs to God.
- this is confirmed by the Greek LXX translation which reads: ὁ θρόνος σου, ὁ θεός, εἰς αἰῶνα αἰῶνος,... = The throne of You, O God is forever and ever ... "
- the Hebrew (unlike the Greek) does not have a vocative case and so uses the equivalent of the nominative case as reflected in the Greek
- this interpretation is further confirmed by the angel to Mary in Luke 1:31-33 - " ... His kingdom will never end."

**Hebrews 1:8**

Again, the text of this verse is:

> πρὸς δὲ τὸν Υἱόν Ὁ θρόνος σου ὁ Θεὸς εἰς τὸν αἰῶνα τοῦ αἰῶνος, καὶ ἡ
> ῥάβδος τῆς εὐθύτητος ῥάβδος τῆς βασιλείας αὐτοῦ. = Unto the Son [He
> says]: "The throne of you, O God, is forever and ever ... "

We pause only long enough to note that this reflects the LXX wording very closely.
Daniel B Wallace in his "Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics", p59, deals with this verse specifically when he offers these comments:

> There are three possibilities for Θεὸς here: as subject ("God is your
> throne"; predicate ("your throne is God"); and nominative for vocative
> ("You throne O God is forever ..."). The S and PN translations can be
> lumped together and set off against the nominative for vocative
> approach. It is our view that the nominative for vocative view is to
> be preferred for the following reasons:
>
> 1. It is an overstatement to argue that if a writer wanted to address God he could have used the vocative Θεε, because no where in the NT is
>    this done except in Matt 27:46.  The articular nominative for vocative
>    is the almost universal choice
> 2. This is especially the case in quoting from the LXX (as in Heb 1:8; cf Heb 10:7), for the LXX is equally reticent to use the vocative
>    form, most likely since Hebrew lacked such a form.
> 3. The accentuation in the Hebrew of Ps 45:7(6) suggests that there should be a pause between "throne" and "God" (indicating that
>    tradition took "God" as direct address).
> 4. This view takes seriously the μὲν ... δὲ construction of vv7-8, while the S-PN does not adequately handle these constructions.
>    Specifically, if we v8 as "your throne if God" the δὲ loses its
>    adversative force, for such a statement could also be made of angels,
>    viz., that God reigns over them.

Comment: "Your throne [is] the God forever and ever." Christ's throne will endure forever and is supported by God his Father. As a throne supports a sitting body, God the Father is the gardener who supports the vine of Christ by watering it. Jesus is not God, but the Son of the living God.

Comment: @JoshuaB - stop putting words in my mouth.  Heb 1:8 & 9 both say that the Father declares Jesus to be "God" , that is, ho theos - God in the highest sense.

Comment: Actually, Hebrews 1:8 & 9 both say that the Father declares Jesus to be exalted above all things yet underneath only God his Father, and that his authority comes from God and is everlasting.

Answer (score 0):

OP's question,  "

> Wouldn't this passage be saying that the throne of God's king comes from God and thereby represents his sovereign authority on earth? It certainly cannot be saying that the king himself is literally God."

I would say yes, and a few more things to substantiate that.

> Yet to the Son:  Thy throne, O God is for the eon of the eon. Heb.1:8. CLT

> Therefore, God, Thy God, anoints Thee with the oil of exaltation beyond the partners.
> Heb.1:9

> We know the Son is the emblem of the divine assumptions. God assumes various characters during His administration of the eons. He is Creator, Savior, Judge and Reconciler. In every assumption He is represented by His Son who, as His Emblem is also Creator, Savior, Judge and Reconciler. Concordant commentary Heb.11

> As Christ, He reigns over the next eon, including the thousand years. After that, in the new earth. He reigns as son. This is called "the eon of eon ", because it is the fruit of His reign during the proceeding eon. The Son has reigned to such purpose that there is no further need of His rule, He abdicates, turning over the kingdom to God.  CLT commentary

> Then the end will come, when He hands over the kingdom to God the Father after He has destroyed all dominion, authority, and power. For He must reign until He has put all His enemies under His feet. The last enemy to be destroyed is death. For  “God has put everything under His feet.”Now when it says that everything has been put under Him, this clearly does not include the One who put everything under Him. And when all things have been subjected to Him, then the Son Himself will be made subject to Him who put all things under Him, so that God may be all in all.  1 Co 15:28.

€Thy throne, O God, [is] age-during, and for ever, A sceptre of uprightness [Is] the sceptre of Thy kingdom.
Thou hast loved righteousness and hatest wickedness, Therefore God, thy God, hath anointed thee, Oil of joy above thy companions. Psalm 45.6-7